# Radeditor Document manager does not display files and folders

Tags: html, css, telerik, dotnetnuke, radeditor

I have a problem with version 6.1.5 of Dnn, since yesterday inexplicably files and folders within the document manager of RadEditor are no longer visible, but within the filemanager of Directors are all visible, I state that I have not run update of dnn.
I tried to perform a recursive synchro but nothing. I followed this link http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/199/threadid/446739/scope/posts/threadpage/1 but nothing together. I'm losing hope of solving this problem.
this is my screen shot problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/96lbrez57qla547/Conosci%20La%20Provincia.png

this is stack error:

DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.FileManagerException: Unable to complete operation. An unknown error occurred. /Portals/0 ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.FileSystemValidation.get_UserFolders() at DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.FileSystemValidation.GetUserFolder(String path) at DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.TelerikFileBrowserProvider.AddChildDirectoriesToList(DirectoryItem[]& radDirectories, Boolean recursive, Boolean loadFiles) at DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.TelerikFileBrowserProvider.ResolveRootDirectoryAsTree(String path) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution before I changed the path of the folders in the Folders table, after I modified the physical path of the folder, putting them all in lower case so as to have a situation sepculare to the table, then I run a recursive sync the file manager on the host and subsequently that of the admin.
The problem seems to have disappeared, although I did not understand what was owed.
will investigate to find out why since the day before it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by checking if you have a duplicate entry in the folders or fills take in your database

Comment: I have verified that there are no duplicates in the db folder, I found none.